# page with page Type not found

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x

interesting pageType issue for those who are interested:

I have a normal ajax call to a page with a pagetype number. On my dev machine, it works (osx with apache PHP 5.5), on my staging (linux / apache / php 5.5 )I get a pageType not configured error.

Now the funny part is:

the pagetype is 6732740021, but the error states it can not find a page with page type 2147483647.

Anyone has ever had this weird problem ?

Comment: seems like a int overflow.  My dev is 64bit, staging is not.  case closed

Comment: Please post the solution as an answer and accept it